# Connecting Sphero 2.0 to Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: c#, ios, macos, unity-game-engine, sphero-api

I just bought a Sphero 2.0 and I want to connect it to my Mac so I could use the Unity SDK. I cannot seem to connect it via bluetooth on my macbook pro. What do I need to do to get my sphero connected so I could start developing. I have the desktop api and the unity sdk already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sphero Unity plugin currently only supports iOS and Android.  There isn't support for Mac OS via the Sphero Unity plugin and we don't have any immediate plans to add it.

However, all the pieces are out there if you would like to put them together and build the support yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial SDK for MAC here: https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Mac-SDK